# problem with animating resizing agdatagridcolumn !

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

i want resize width of agdatagridcolumn in a agdatagrid with animation code
:

```
 (CreateStb(agdatagrid)).Begin();//Exceptin: Cannot resolve TargetProperty Width  on    specified object.
.
.
Private StoaryBoard CreateStb(UIElement element)
{
  Storyboard stb = new Storyboard();
  DoubleAnimation dbAnmtin = new DoubleAnimation();
  Storyboard.SetTarget(dbAnmtin, (AgDataGridColumn)((AgDataGrid)element).Columns[0]);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dbAnmtin, new PropertyPath("Width"));
  dbAnmtin1.To=//custom value
  dbAnmtin1.Duration=//custom value
  stb.Children.Add(dbAnmtin);
  Return stb;
```

}

I think defining TargetProperty has a problem but I don’t know how to solve it .
plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Check your documentation for `AgDataGridColumn`, is the `Width` property implemented as a DependencyProperty ?  You can only animate dependency propeties.